# Cuda cudaGetTextureReference returns "invalid texture reference"

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, cuda, gpgpu, cuda-arrays

Im developing a small cuda lib, stuck by this annoying tex ref issue.

This is the sample code from Cuda C Programming Guide, Page43~44:

```
texture<float, cudaTextureType2D,cudaReadModeElementType> texRef;
textureReference* texRefPtr;
cudaGetTextureReference(&texRefPtr, "texRef");
cudaChannelFormatDesc channelDesc;
cudaGetChannelDesc(&channelDesc, cuArray);
cudaBindTextureToArray(texRef, cuArray, &channelDesc);
```

When i execute it, the line cudaGetTextureReference(...) returns the error code `cudaErrorInvalidTexture`.
I couldn't find many other samples about cudaGetTextureReference on the internet, most of them are following the exact same procedure as the sample code above.

Frustrated, i tried the high-level API afterwards:

```
texture<float, cudaTextureType2D,cudaReadModeElementType> texRef;
cudaBindTextureToArray(texRef, cuArray);
```

same problem.
If read from that texture in the kernel, zero values are all i get.

My full toy test code, 100% reproduce-rate:  (win7, cuda 5.0)

```
texture<float, cudaTextureType2D, cudaReadModeElementType> texRef;

int main ()
{
    const textureReference *tref = NULL;
    checkSuccess( cudaGetTextureReference( &tref, "texRef" ) );
    pauseConsole();
    return 0;
}
```

Any insight for this problem would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Use of a string naming a variable as the symbol paramater was removed
>   in CUDA 5.0.

Stated in [CUDA Toolkit Reference Manual 5.0](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/index.html#group__CUDART__TEXTURE_1g2caa86a0bf6975b64c0028462301924c), Section 5.20.2.8 /Note.

Do the following instead:

```
cudaGetTextureReference( &tref, &texRef );
```

Comment: Ive read that bit too. But, the code you provided will not compile.

Comment: @Defd.. sorry, as talonmies pointed out, there was a mistake in the code.

Answer (score 3):

Pass the symbol directly, not as a string. The string look method is a deprecated version of the API that was removed completely in CUDA 5. Your texture lookup should be written as

```
cudaGetTextureReference( &tref, &texRef );
```

Comment: This looks unfriendly with c++ syntax. I get this: no suitable conversion function from "texture<float, 2, cudaReadModeElementType>" to "const void *" exists.  Can you elaborate a little more about the details?

Comment: @Defd: sorry, made a very small typo. The call requires a reference to the texture, not its value. I usually put a disclaimer if I haven't actually tried to compile and run any code I post. This time I didn't.....

Comment: thank you for the fast clarification. Unfortunately stackoverflow only allows me to select one correct answer. sgar91's answer looks more canonical. I think it's better for the sake of a QA site like this. Anyway, thanks and kudos for you.